# Mongo&Express - what are the practical ways to avoid client firing same req multiple times?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

**Introduction:**

I am developing a liking system similar to normal facebook liking where each user can like each post only once. I need to develop this system and have a "totalLike" in mongoDB. Environment: Mongoose, Express on server-side, Nextjs(React) on client-side.

**Problem:**

When user spams clicking the LIKE button before the button re-render to UNLIKE, the express LIKE api could be fired multiple times causing the extra number to be put into "totalLike". For example, you clicked like 3 times very fast, there you get 3 totalLikes instead of 1. (noted: I choose to add totalLike to user to avoid too many nested populate when call in the future)

**My Pseudo-code:**

Simply +1 totalLikes when press like and -1 totalLikes when press unlike. And it should be just that !

```
router.patch(
  '/like/:post',
  (req, res, next) => {
     // user_id = the_user_who_click_like_to:post
     Post.updateOne( 
        // at this post, add the user_id LikedUser array, then ...
        (res) => {
             User.updateOne(
                 // at user_id, do { $inc: { totalLikes: 1 } }, <-- this is the problem
                 // because "totalLikes" could be plus more than once!
)})})

router.delete(
   '/like/:post',
   // Do the same but opposite, $pull user_id from Post and -1 totalLikes in User = face same problem as above
)
```

**Now the questions:**

1. What are the practical ways to avoid this from happening on
   server-side?
2. Is blocking the client-side from firing normally done by only setting state to disabling React button ?
3. As a backend newbie, another improved approach for the shown Psuedo code would be eye candy.

Comment: [an idempotency token, perhaps?](https://youtu.be/IP-rGJKSZ3s?t=308)

Comment: The video gives me a good knowledge about idempotence and I am clear with its theory now. So I tried using PUT instead of PATCH but it is still doing the same behavior. Could you guide me what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are of course different approaches you can use.

Usually people to like posts have to be logged in and thus have an account.

This enables you to store in the DB, attached to the user, the like.

When you get a request to like something you can just check if the user has liked that already or not and throw an error in case it's present.

Another way, of course not 100% safe (the first would be), is to use the browser's Memory Storage or send back a cookie.

You would again check if there is this cookie or not before processing the request.

Of course you would then add front-end code to show the like button as inactive if the user has liked it before or popup a login window if he is not logged in.

It's very hard to show a full functional code as it's a pretty big topic, but I hope these directives may help.

Comment: _When you get a request to like something you can just check if the user has liked that already or not and throw an error in case it's present._ <- Yes, I should have done this witchcraft! It seems performance consuming but worthier than having fault data.

Comment: You can store the reference to an object "like" in an array in the User object and check upon that, that way you are just storing ids and it's not too bad!

Comment: I considered about that previously but I am not sure about its impacts when data gets larger. Would that cause bloated performance when I "find user data without selecting the likedPosts (the array that you suggest about)"?

Comment: I don’t think it will be too bad! It’s actually the usual way to do it, going with referenceIds with Mongo..